# Excel VLOOKUP unable to reference data

Tags: excel

I would like to use `VLOOKUP` function to bring back the values from other worksheet. However, Excel could only partially 'look-up' those values while displaying some of the actual existing values as `#N\A` or `0`. Any settings I could do to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you trying to look to the left on a Vlookup? If so it just wont work and will bring up errors as you are getting. Try using index match instead as that will work no matter which way round you have your columns.

If you can show an example of what you got it will make this easier to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLOOKUP will return 0 if there is there is no value in the specified return column , in the specified range, for the lookup value stated.

It will return #N/A if the lookup value cannot be found in the specified range.
You need to be sure there isn't hidden white space and that datatypes are the same if you believe the lookup value exists in the lookup range. You can use combinations of Trim and Substitute to get rid of white space. Datatypes you need to investigate and handle as appropriate.

To get rid of the zero make sure there is a value in the return column of the specified lookup range.

To get rid of the #N/A you could decide on a default return value and use IFERROR to return that value for any #N/A found.

[image: Examples]

Column E shows the formulas in column D.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...However, I've checked that some #N/A do actually have values in the specified return column, that's what I'm frustrating with. I'm not gonna decide on my default instead of bringing back the true values.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. #N/A is not about the specified return column. It is about the lookup value. And concerning the lookup value, you need to be sure there isn't hidden white space and that datatypes are the same. Did you mark the answer down under this misconception?